# JPA returns many times the same object

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I'm trying to use JPA as a REST service using jax-rs. I'm trying to get all the values from an entity. In the db theres only one object, but this entity have a relationship one to many to other entity. Everything goes fine, but when I see the response in any RESTclient (I'm using POSTman) I get the same object many times.

```
@GET
@Path("/by")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List getAll() {
    Query q = entityManager.createQuery("select u from Entity u");

    List<A> x = q.getResultList();
    List<A> fg = new ArrayList<A>();
    for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
        A l = (A) x.get(i);
        l.getMonto();
        fg.add(l);
    }
    return fg;
}
```

Comment: Does your entity PaymentPlan  have composite id? I remember one of the problem  :- I was having an entity with composite id but id was not same in database due to which there were multiple rows with same composite id in database. So when we fired a query through hibernate it was loading exact number of rows but object were repeated for rows having same composite id.

Comment: What is the purpose of the trailing `u`?

Comment: The trailing u is a standard part of the JPQL syntax.

Comment: So the SQL actually invoked is what ? and the when you invoke that SQL manually in your datastore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't clear the `EntityManager` before you did not get the target result. According to your query, the query will retrieve all of the record from `PaymentPlan` table.

```
Query q = entityManager.createQuery("select u from PaymentPlan u");
PaymentPlan paymentPlan = (PaymentPlan)q.getSingleResult();
```

or

```
Query q = entityManager.createQuery("select u from PaymentPlan u");
List<PaymentPlan> paymentPlanList = q.getResultList();
PaymentPlan paymentPlan = paymentPlanList.get(0);
```

Comment: I'm getting the same behavior. When I see the method, the response only contains 1 object, but when I use POSTman, I get the same objecte infinite times.

Answer (score 1):

```
Query q = entityManager.createQuery("select u from PaymentPlan u");
PaymentPlan pp = (PaymentPlan)q.getSingleResult();
```

This will Return single Result. getSingleResult() Execute a SELECT query that returns a single untyped result.

See this link for more - http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/execute

Comment: I'm getting the same behavior. When I see the answer in POSTman, theres an infinite number of the same object